# finite product of artinian rings is artinian

Tags: proof-verification, modules

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two left (resp. right) Artinian rings. I would like to prove $R_1\times R_2$ is also a left (resp. right) Artinian ring.

My proof is the following (only for left):

Let $A_1\ge A_2\ge A_3\ge\cdots$ be a decreasing chain of left ideals of $R_1\times R_2$. Then we can rewrite the chain as $$S_1\times T_1\ge S_2\times T_2\ge\cdots,$$where $S_i$ and $T_i$ are ideals of $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively.

Then since both $R_1$ and $R_2$ are artinian, the set $\{S_1,S_2,\ldots\}$ and $\{T_1,T_2\ldots\}$ have minimal element, say $S_i$ and $T_j$. Let $k=\max\{i,j\}$. Then $S_1\times T_1\ge S_2\times T_2\ge\cdots$ stabilizes at $S_k\times T_k$.

Could you please help to check if my proof is rigorous? Is there a more obvious (easier) way to show this claim?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it clear that each ideal of $R_1\times R_2$ has the form $S\times T$?

Comment: Well, this can be proved easily that if $A$ is an ideal of $R_1\times R_2$, then it has to be of the form $S\times T$ with $S$ and $T$ ideals of $R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for editing!

Comment: Do you have a reference for this property of ideals in the product?

Comment: Hello @Bernard, which property? Any ideal of $R_1\times R_2$ can be written into product?

Comment: Yes. I don't remember such a propzerty – but I haven't worked with artinian ring for quite some time…

Comment: @Bernard It's a general property of rings. Let $K$ be an ideal of $R\times S$; then $I=\{r:(r,0)\in K\}$ is an ideal of $R$ and $J=\{s:(0,s)\in K\}$ is an ideal of $S$. Next, $I\times J\subseteq K$, because $r\in I$ and $s\in J$ implies $(r,s)=(r,0)+(0,s)\in K$. Conversely, if $(r,s)\in K$, then $(1,0)(r,s)=(r,0)\in K$ and similarly for $J$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modulo the proof that every ideal of $R_1\times R_2$ is of the form $I_1\times I_2$ for $I_i$ and ideal of $R_1$ and $I_2$ an ideal of $R_2$ (easy and well-known), the proof is mostly good.

However you should also mention that from $S_i\times T_i\supseteq S_{i+1}\times T_{i+1}$ it follows that $S_i\supseteq S_{i+1}$ and $T_i\supseteq T_{i+1}$.

Since both chains in the component rings stabilize, also the chain in the product stabilizes.